# Synonym request: [access-specifier] with [access-modifiers]

Tags: support, synonym-request

These seem to be exact duplicates:

- [access-modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-modifiers) (581 questions)
- [access-specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-specifier) (159 questions)

Comment: *access [access-specifier] using [access-modifiers]*